# Sharepoint Views

Tags: 2007

I have two roles on my site, I have a created a custom list. I want to display different views for each of the two roles. One is Normal user where he can only add data. The other one is Special user where he can see various records coming from all other users and can perform CRUD operations on the List and its items.

I have created two different views. Whenever user logs in, depending on the permissions, the proper view should be displayed.

I have tried to target the Web Part using target audience option in the Web Part. But in that case Special users cannot select a different view directly.

How could I do this?

Hari Gillala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could proceed:

- display two views on a page, one that targets the "special user" (using audiences), the other for everybody. The special user will see both views.
- under advanced settings in the list, say that normal users can only see their own items

Comment: I have done that. Thats works fine. But the problem is when the admin logis in they were able to see the a webpart list with no items in it. I have to take that one off from the display. And also Administartors should not be able to edit all the columns, Some columns should be read only. How do I do that.

Manay Thanks

Comment: Hiding a list with no items, making some columns read only: there are no easy answers, and each of these questions would deserve a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to add security to a view is to add that page to a doc lib and lock down the permissions.  A write up can be found on my blog: http://www.mattbramer.blogspot.com.  Search for Views+Security.

For completeness: http://mattbramer.blogspot.com/2010/05/security-trim-list-views-with-ease.html

Answer (score 0):

Hari - There was a [similar thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4443/is-setting-permissions-on-views-now-possible-sharepoint-foundation/4508#4508) a while back that may be of interest to you. There are some good things to consider in this post.