# Restricting Views in Libraries based on Roles

Tags: list-view

I have the default view for a library set and it works great.  I have 3 other views that are more for testing and to make editing custom fields easier for Administration staff.

How can I restrict these 3 additional views to a certain role-specific user? Can you do this based off a group?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is setting permissions on views now possible?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4443/is-setting-permissions-on-views-now-possible)

Comment: @CitizenDB not to nitpick, but the question you linked is SP2010.  OP has not provided his or her version of SharePoint.  While the answer is the same regardless, I do not know if it is considered a duplicate if the version is 2013 or SPO.  Perhaps a moderator can provide input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Audience feature**.

1. You choose the view that you want to restrict.
2. Edit the page.
3. Edit the web part.
4. In the web part under `Audience` enter the group that you want to be able to see this view.
5. Repeat the process for the other views.

This video explains it in more detail.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5zMgGTq9Z4

Comment: Don't have a version of SP that supports it, from what I understand (audiences).  I had to use a javascript class to target content based on groups for some other items, not sure how to get it to play well with views.